# How come this object is released right after it's instantiated? From a book example I'm learning from:

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
BlueViewController *blueController = [[ BlueViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlueView" bundle:nil];
self.blueViewController = blueController;
[self.view insertSubview:blueController.view atIndex:0];
[blueController release];
```

Comment: By the way, unless this code sample was done in conjunction with view controller containment (and judging from the date of your post, I'd guess not), I'd suggest you throw that book away. If this code sample was intended to demonstrate how to transition between views, this is a horrible technique to add a controller's view as a subview and not do anything with the controller itself. Wow, this book suggested some horrible code!

Answer (score 2):

Note this line:

```
self.blueViewController = blueController;
```

My guess is that `blueViewController` property defined with retain attribute, so your object takes ownership of newly created object and then release in the last line we just decrease object's retain count back to 1 to avoid memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The `release` is for the local, temporary reference, which is owned locally because of the `alloc`. Before releasing, it is passed to the view, which will `retain` it for its own purposes, and to the object's own `blueViewController` setter, which will likewise.

Answer (score 1):

`self.blueViewController = blueController;` isn't just assignment. It is equal to:
`[self setBlueViewController];` generated by `@synthesize blueViewController` instruction at the start of .m file. In this setter method passed blueController is copied or retained (depends on @propertioes options in the .h file). If it was copied - you don't need original one. If it was retained, retain count after `self.blueViewController = blueController;` equals 2. By releasing `blueController` they set retain counter to 1.

It is common practice. If you pass "temp" variable to setter or other method with stores referense, those methods retain passed object. So you release it after that. If you temrorary object is autoreleased, then you don't need to release it.
Please read [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)